# Why is this usage of python F-string interpolation wrapping with quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.6, specifications, string-interpolation, f-string

Code in question:

```
a = 'test'

# 1)
print(f'{a}') # test

# 2)
print(f'{ {a} }') # {'test'}

# 3)
print(f'{{ {a} }}') # {test}
```

My question is, why does case two print those quotes?

I didn't find anything explicitly in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). The closest thing I found detailing this was in the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for this feature:

(the grammar for F-strings)

```
f ' <text> { <expression> <optional !s, !r, or !a> <optional : format specifier> } <text> ... '
```

> The expression is then formatted using the **format** protocol, using
>   the format specifier as an argument. The resulting value is used when
>   building the value of the f-string.

I suppose that the value of `a` is being formatted with some formatter, which, since the data type is a string, wraps it with quotes. This result is then returned to the surrounding F-string formatting instance.

Is this hypothesis correct? Is there some other place which documents this more clearly?

Comment: Your link to 2.7 doc will not have anything about a 3.6 feature.  Instead, https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `f'{ {a} }'`, the `{a}` (as indicated by the grammar) is interpreted as a Python expression.  In Python, `{a}` constructs a `set` of one element (`a`), and the `str`ingification of a set uses the `repr` of its elements, which is where the quotes come from.

Comment: Nested {}s are recognized as a nested replacement field only in the optional format specification (after ':').  That they have their normal meaning in the replacement expression, and result in a set, can be verified by executing `print(f'{ { {a} } }')`