# String formatting with quotation marks

Tags: python, string-formatting

Say I have a list

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

And I want to create the following strings:

```
foo_a = bar['a']
foo_b = bar['b']
foo_c = bar['c']
```

I tried the following:

```
for i in list:
    print("foo_{} = bar['{{}}']".format(i))
```

But the output is

```
foo_a = bar['{}']
foo_b = bar['{}']
foo_c = bar['{}']
```

I have read [Why is this usage of python F-string interpolation wrapping with quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112098/why-is-this-usage-of-python-f-string-interpolation-wrapping-with-quotes) but the second method does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: Can you please show what the ideal outlook would look like?

Comment: @Greg See the second snippet, `foo_a = bar['a'] ...`. I guess OP is doing code generation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two `{}` place-holders but only one variable. So you need to let those place-holders know they need to use the same one. Also, for some reason you use double-braces in the second place-holder. This is used to "escape" the braces, so `{{}}` will become `{}` (and not serve as an actual place-holder).

So after fixing these two issues:

```py
>>> list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i in list:
        print("foo_{i} = bar['{i}']".format(i=i))
     #  print("foo_{0} = bar['{0}']".format(i))

foo_a = bar['a']
foo_b = bar['b']
foo_c = bar['c']
```

Or with `f-strings` (for Python `>= 3.6`):

```py
for i in list:
    print(f"foo_{i} = bar['{i}']")
```

---

To better understand the use of place holders, read more at [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info), specifically the [Basic Formatting](https://pyformat.info/#simple) part for info about positional place-holders, and the [Named place-holders](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders) part for - well - named place-holders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You're missing a few things.

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in list:
    print("foo_{} = bar[\'{}\']".format(i, i))
```

Comment: There's no need to escape the single quotes when they're in a double-quoted string literal.